# Does WPF have a way of saving radio button content and then sent the save content through a event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

I was wondering if it possible for WPF to save the radio button content and use the event handler to sent the content to text file. Do I need to do all that in the event handler or i can invoke some class?

```
    public void method(){
string s = "Test1&Test2&Test3&Test4";

string[] s = Spliting.Split(new string[] { "&" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

List<RadioButton> radioButtonList = new List<RadioButton>();

        radioButtonList.Add(radioButton);
        radioButtonList.Add(radioButton1);

    for (int i = 0; i < radioButtonList.Count; i++)
{

//some code that insert string into the radio button (done)
//when i use streamwriter inside here, it give me this in the text file
//System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton Content IsChecked:False <- this can be turn to true if i put variable.Checked = true
}

private void radioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (radioButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            StreamWriter streamwriters = new StreamWriter ("Sent.txt", false);
            streamwriters.Close();
        }
        else if (radioButton1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            StreamWriter streamwriters = new StreamWriter("Sent.txt", false);
            streamwriters.Close();
        }
```

Or WPF have a method that can automatically save the content into variable. Am I missing something?

I wanted the radio button to check the radio button and sent the content into the text file.

Comment: What "saved content"? It's a two (or three) state bool, nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to save the text displayed with the radio button to a file, then:

```
private void radioButton1_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string radioButtonContent = ((RadioButton)sender).Text;
    string savePath = @"C:\sent.txt"; // or wherever

    File.WriteAllText(savePath, radioButtonContent);
}
```